# I got an error in appending a dataframe row from one to another dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

`frontbar1_v_elements, frontbar1_h_elements, rearbar_elements, sidebar_up_elements, sidebar_down_elements`  are the lists. `draft_indep` is a dataframe with only one row and multiple columns, all cell attended as zero. `total1` is a 2D list. The code is dedicated to change "1" to some certain "0" in `a1` according to `total1`. It works well to until this line. But the row in a1 could not be appended to `main_indep` which is a dataframe. By the way, `a1` was deep copied from `draft_indep` and `draft_indep` deep copied from `main_indep`.

```
total1=[frontbar1_v_elements,frontbar1_h_elements,rearbar_elements,sidebar_up_elements,sidebar_down_elements]
a1=draft_indep.copy()
for single in total1:
   for ele in single:
       a1.at[0,ele]=int(1)
        
main_indep.append(a1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: From kwquan (still not enough rep. to comment): What do you mean by stucked? Did you get an error or does main_indep remain the same after appending?

Comment: Yes, main_indep remains the same after appending.

Comment: `append` does not modify the dataframe, it returns a modified dataframe so you want something like `main_indep = main_indep.append(a1, ignore_index=True)`